# Хороша ли идея использовать VPS сервер для разработки?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Стоит ли отказаться от локального окружения / vagrant в пользу аренды своей VPS? Цены сейчас не слишком высокие.

Comment: А зачем?. . . .

Comment: Вы, например, можете делать  разработку локально, а тестовый билд выкладывать на VSP (для демонстрации вашему заказчику, либо для тестирования в реальной среде, если финальная версия будет работать на том самом VPS). Зависит от ваших потребностей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недостатки разработки на VPS:

- необходимо регулярно платить арендную плату (даже если проект активно не разрабатывается)
- отправка изменений файлов на удалённый сервер происходит по сети, а поэтому может происходить с задержкой
- возможность разработки напрямую зависит от наличия интернета
- необходимо администрировать удалённый сервер (поднять, защитить от атак, общаться с техподдержкой хостера в случае падений и сбоев железа)

Преимущества разработки на VPS:

- <не смог найти>

Напрашивается вывод: **переходить на VPS для разработки не стоит**.

Comment: а если и брать, то обычный шаред, его админить хоть не надо, и уже всё настроено по максимуму.